# Felogin passwords are not converted to argon2i on login during typo3 upgrade

Tags: typo3, upgrade, argon2-ffi, felogin

I was doing an upgrade from Typo3 7 to Typo3 10. I am using felogin plugin for user login. In the documentations it is saying that the old salted passwords of users will get automatically converted to argon2i. But in my case, the login is not happening and also the passwords are not getting converted. For a new user created, this works perfectly. But the old salted passwords are not getting converted. Is there any other configurations we have to do?

Thank you

Comment: Please also mention what hashing algorithm was used before / is used for the existing password hashes.

Comment: Salted passwords was using before. Now argon2id hashing mechanism is used as my php version is 7.4

Comment: Salted passwords are a feature, not a hashing algorithm like Argon2i, SHA-1 or MD5.

Comment: Seems like MD5 hashing is used. Old passwords are starting with $1$.

Comment: That indeed seems to be MD5.

Comment: I have checked typo3 7 version to see which hashing is used. But as in typo3 10, it is not showing the hashing mechanism. But all the passwords are starting with $1$.
For typo3 10, argon2id is used. For new passwords argon2id is created. But the old ones are not getting converted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245854/discussion-between-mathias-brodala-and-ques).

Answer (score 2):

A direct conversion from legacy password hashes using MD5 to newer algorithms is not supported anymore.

Up to TYPO3v8 there was a scheduler task you could use to upgrade the password hashes. This was [removed with TYPO3v9](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.3/Important-85026-SaltedpasswordsChanges.html#salted-passwords-bulk-update-task-removed) so you should first upgrade to TYPO3v8, upgrade the password hashes and then continue to upgrade to newer TYPO3 versions:

> If there are still clear-text or simple md5 stored passwords, they can be found by searching the database field password of tables fe_users and be_users for entries not starting with $. If there are still entries like that, an administrator should convert them to simple md5 salted hashes by using the convert bulk update scheduler task in a core version prior to v9, before upgrading the system to v9.